# How to create a cache system for map areas queries

Tags: caching, dictionary, coordinates

I'm asking to a database of points (lat/lng) specific areas, for example, from lat1,lng1 to lat2, lng2 . That generates like "square areas queries".

Then after some queries (caching those areas coordinates), I'd like to know if a query (a set of coordinates) are completely inside the areas cached before or not, so I'd decide to ask data internally to a cached table, or query against the remote server (more time).

You can see example in this map: http://cl.ly/image/3l1o1v2i2g3P

Red squares are previous queries. 
Blue square 1 is the new query, and it's all inside red queries, so I can be safe to take all data from my cached data.
But blue square 2 has some "new subareas", so I'd have to take from remote server all data.

How can I know, then, where an area is cached in a bunch of areas or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at quadtrees. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: But that algorithm helps me to check if something is colliding something, but no to check if something is completely inside "a group of somethings" ... isn't it ? :P

Comment: The algorithm is also used for spatial indexing. It is structuring data in such a way that it is very fast when it comes to knowing which data is a sub part of other data. Its strength is that it is fast and relatively simple. However you need to fetch predefined blocks, and thus a little bit more data than you need. But that shouldn't be a problem. Simplicity and speed weighs up for that.